# Java Streams: Grouping a list by a value that is not in the list returns a map containing non-exiting value as a key and an original list as a value?

Tags: java, java-stream

This may be a silly question but, I'm trying to understand why following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> testData = Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c");
    Map<String, List<String>> grouped = testData.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> "z"));
    System.out.println(grouped);
}
```

would return back a map:

```
{z=[a, b, c]}
```

I'm trying here to segment a list by the value that is not in the list. As a result I would expect back the following:

```
{z=[]}
```

In my case classifier function is not that simple, but in a nutshell it may produce a classifier value that is not amongst list values.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `groupingBy` is not a filtering function. Each stream element will always end up in one of the created groups, your grouping function is only telling in which one.

Comment: suppose you have a list `a, b,c,d` and you segment by `c` what would the map look like? `{c = [c,d]}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Collectors.groupingBy` will group all of your Items in a `Map<Key,List<Item>>` based on the **Key** that the function returns. 
You are returning the same key "z" for all your items, so they all get grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer explains how group by works. I am not sure If understood your requirement completely. But you might want to see if `partitioningBy` could help you.

```
List<String> testData = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "z");
Map<Boolean, List<String>> grouped = testData.stream()
                                                    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(item -> item.equals("z")));
System.out.println(grouped);
```

will always print a map with 2 keys.

```
{false=[a, b, c], true=[z]}
```

Comment: I had the same idea, but I don't think this is correct. What would be the output if you segment by `b` for example?